# Spray-Json - How to define field constraints

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

I have case class which represents my json model:

```
case class UserData(photo_url: String, age: Int, bio: String)
```

and wondering how could I define some constraints on some specific fields, like length for `bio` or value range for `age`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't control serialization / deserialization process in spray-json, unfortunately. The only way to implement that is to use your [custom serializer](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types) and put constraints there.